# Redirect to default in Web Api Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My problem: When a session expires user still can perform an action (search). Action results are some garbage (controller is not visited). I don't know why; I just want to redirect a user to login page.

My plan is to make custom Authorize and override HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext) and redirect a user to index.
I have no idea how to redirect to my default page.

Sample code:

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        //redirect here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to set Response of `actionContext` to `Unauthorized` http response. Here's a sample how to do so.

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext) {

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    }
}
```

This should hopefully redirect user to the page you (hopefully) defined in `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.

Edit: To be honest, this kind of defined the purpose of Web API if you let users access it in the same way as you would enter a normal page. You should on the client determine if response from the web api endpoint was `success`, `unathorized` etc. You should be returning that instead of direct `redirect` from the web api.

If you really wanted to redirect, you might try the following...

```
var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
actionContext.Response = response;
```

Again, I don't see the point in redirecting from Web API. It should only return the requested data/errors. You should be processing it else where.

Comment: Yea... so - here is the problem: I have HttpActionContext, and You gave me an example with AuthorizationContext. My actionContext doesn't contain  Result

Comment: @CapitanPlanet Of course, my bad. I tend to assume things I usually work on :-) Updated the answer.

Comment: figured this out, but it doesn't work... It has not redirected me. I'm still on the same page.

Comment: first example doesn't work at all; in second example I don't receive garbage data. 

WTF? it should be simple thing.

Comment: @CapitanPlanet You don't understand. You don't seem to understand the purpose of an API too. Please read what I wrote again.

Comment: You are right...I have not understand it. My friend helped me, and i had problem on client side, not Web Api.

Answer (score -1):

I thought I can redirect to site directly from Web API... Well, I can't. Turned out I don't need custom Authorize, because [Authorize] redirect correctly. I need my client to redirect when Authorize wants. In my case (Angular 1,5) it was an interceptor.

```
app.service('httpRedirectInterceptor', ['$window', function ($window) {
this.response = function (redirection) {
    if (typeof redirection.data === 'string') {
        if (redirection.data.indexOf instanceof Function &&
            redirection.data.indexOf('id="app-login-page"') != -1) {
            $window.location.pathname = "/Account/Login";
        }
    }
    return redirection;
};

this.request = function (req) {
    var elem = angular.element(document.body).find('div[ncg-request-verification-token]').attr('ncg-request-verification-token');
    req.headers['RequestVerificationToken'] = elem || "no request verification token";

    return req;
};}]);
```

and in app.config

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.
push('httpRedirectInterceptor');
```

Comment: Really? After i have you the answer, you post it as your own and mark it as correct...? Pretty sure that's not how it works.

Comment: Sory... i tout there could be 2 correct answers.  Apparently not